# I try to backup of records to another org

Tags: rest-api, integration

I have a question. When i integrate salesforce to salesforce  I got 160000 record from the response. How can I save record in my org.? I try to backup  of records to another org. IS it possible or not.?
Also suggest the best way to take backup of my org record.

Thanks.

Comment: you can export the data from salesforce as csv. Import the data to other org

Comment: Thanks @DOMINICEDWARD . Can we create it in automatic,  means can we done this through apex class.

Comment: No need of codes... Its functional... try this **quick search** --> **Data Export** --> **Export Now** . Then you can select what object you want to export.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you would like to migrate the metadata (object and fields) to another Salesforce org, you can use either the Force.com IDE or the Force.com Migration Tool.

Once the metadata is migrated, you can then use the Dataloader to export all the data from your current org and then import it into the new org.

You can also use ETL tool such as DBsync to migrate only data from one Salesforce org to another using auto map feature.